# Copy everything under a non specific (*) folders

Tags: batch-file

I'm trying to copy some non specific folders with their content, but can't find a way to do it. My problem is every time I try to use any of the `copy` commands it tells me it's an "**Invalid number of parameters**", or "**0 File(s) copied**", or "**File not found -**", or it copies everything from `Folder1`, (not just the non specific folders).

What I mean by "non specific" is a folder which has an unknown name, i.e. `*`.

This is what I have tried:

```
xcopy /y "C:\Folder1\Something_*" "C:\Folder2"
```

```
copy /y "C:\Folder1\Something_*" "C:\Folder2"
```

```
robocopy "C:\Folder1\Something_*" "C:\Folder2"
```

/+ adding " * " in front of "Something_*"

I have also tried a lot more smaller things, that I don't see a need to add.

I'm a little lost on what to do at this point, and feel like I have been looking everywhere for a solution with no luck.

Edit: i found a way to do this and it's so much better, this is how

```
for /R "%sourcedir%" %%A in (Something_*) do copy /y "C:\Folder1\%%~A" "C:\Folder2"
```

Comment: So - please confirm my interpretation of your goal. You wish to copy every file from each of the directories matching `"C:\Folder1\Something_*"`? Or do you want to copy each of *their* subdirectories also?

Comment: @Magoo i need both the non specific directories with their subdirectories yes, sorry if the working is a little weird, i'm dyslexic so it can be kinda hard sometimes to text what i mean

Comment: Take a look at `help robocopy`.

Comment: @jwdonahue i did, but i couldn't find anything, i looked up on all the copy arguments and no one could do what i wanted

Comment: How about showing us a sample of the directory listing and then tell us exactly which directories are "non specific"?

Comment: copy /y "C:%sourcedir%\<the folder with an unknown name (*)>" "C:\%destdir%"

Answer (score 0):

```batch-file
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
rem The following settings for the source directory, destination directory, target directory,
rem batch directory, filenames, output filename and temporary filename [if shown] are names
rem that I use for testing and deliberately include names which include spaces to make sure
rem that the process works using such names. These will need to be changed to suit your situation.

SET "sourcedir=u:\your files\t w o"
SET "destdir=u:\your results"

:: Version 1 - all files arrive in the destination directory

FOR /f "delims=" %%b IN ('dir /b /ad "%sourcedir%\Something_*" ') DO (
 COPY /b /y "%sourcedir%\%%b\*" "%destdir%\" >NUL 2>nul
 FOR /f "delims=" %%c IN ('dir /b /s /ad "%sourcedir%\%%b" ') DO (
  COPY /b /y "%%c\*" "%destdir%\" >NUL 2>nul
 )
)

cls
dir/s "%destdir%"
PAUSE


:: This is a routine I use for testing. It simply deletes the directory named and restores it, empty
CALL deltreey /r "%destdir%">NUL

:: Version 2 - preserve tree structure

FOR /f "delims=" %%b IN ('dir /b /ad "%sourcedir%\Something_*" ') DO XCOPY /y /s /e "%sourcedir%\%%b" "%destdir%\" >NUL 2>nul
)

cls
dir/s "%destdir%"
PAUSE

:: This is a routine I use for testing. It simply deletes the directory named and restores it, empty
CALL deltreey /r "%destdir%">NUL



GOTO :EOF
```

Comment: so i have just tested both versions, and they are not working how i meant, i didn't mean the files in the folder like it's the files that is gonna get moved, i just mean they where gonna be moved as normally with the folder (i couldn't even get that to work), it's the folder being an unknown name that is the problem for me, but thanks for the help! :D

Comment: if you need me to explain it better maybe in a video then just lmk, i can record and speak what i mean with it all, and maybe also show what i wanna use it on

Comment: No need for anything that complex. Try editing into your question a sample "before" directory listing and an "Expected after" directory listing.

Comment: Hey back to this again, anyway i can make the subdirectories wildcards on multiple layers

i'm asking this because now i got another problem where i need wildcards on 4 layers

Comment: Both solutions use `dir ... /b...` Try changing this to `dir ... /s /b ...` which should apply the scan to subdirectories also.

Comment: it doesn't, but i found another way to do it, a much better way `for /R "%sourcedir%" %%A in (*.*) do ..... "%%~A"`